# MySQL returned values are not formatted (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

This is what is stored in my MySQL database:

[image]

But when I query it and display it in the browser, it is shown like this:

[image]

Just one line and not multiple like the original value in MySQL. How can I make my code so it keeps the same format as in the database? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Browsers ignore whitespace. Use HTML formatting like `<br>`. There's even a [function for it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: Show your PHP Code.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will ignore or neglect the `enter` key that you stored in the database. However, browser will recognize the `<br>` tag. Just add the `<br>` in your PHP code when you want to print it out. Alternatively, you can have a look at `nl2br` function. This is the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)